# Quicksort - Worst case condition

Tags: algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I see similar questions to this have been asked before, but I've been searching for a while and can't seem to find an answer.

The assignment I have right now is to use the quicksort algorithm to sort a simple array of 7 letters.
We need to show each step of the sort, underlining the pivot each time.
Our instructor asked that we use the **rightmost** value as the pivot for each step.
Based on this video, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQiWF4E8flQ ,this is what I have so far (pivot in bold):

GACEFB**D**

A|GCEFB**D**

AC|GEFB**D**

ACB|EFG**D**

ACB**D**|FG**E**

But I'm unsure of where to go from here. On the left side of the partition, D is the pivot, but there are no values larger than D. So where does the pivot go?
Every tutorial I've seen uses the median of three as a pivot, or the leftmost, and I'm not the best at algorithms.

Part B has us showing every step of sorting ABCDEFG, with the same rules. Not sure where to begin there, since I have the same problem.
Sorry if this is a dumb question.

Comment: Huh, you've got like a selection-pivot thing going on there.  Works great on paper, not so much in binary arrays.  In real code, we use a different pivot strategy.  Irrelevant to your homework though.

Comment: In the code we were provided, the pivot is selected by finding the median of the array, which makes sense. I think our professor wanted us to change the pivot to the rightmost value to illustrate the worst case runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider what happens on each iteration.

Remember, quick sort works like this:

1. If the array is empty, return an empty array and exit
2. If the array has only one entry, return the entry and exit
3. Choose a pivot
4. Split the array in three sub-arrays:

   - Values smaller than the pivot
   - The pivot
   - Values larger than the pivot
5. For each non-empty array, apply quick sort again and concatenate the resulting arrays

(I know I'm using the word "array" vaguely... but I think the idea is clear)

I think that you're missing a simple fact: Once you choose the pivot, you *put* it in it's right place, and apply quick sort to the other arrays... you don't apply quick sort to the pivot again.

Let's say you have a function called `QuickSort(Array, Pivot)`, and let's assume you always take the left-most entry of the array as pivot:

- Start: `QuickSort(GACEFBD , D)`
- 1st. iteration:

  `[QuickSort(ACB, B), D, QuickSort(GEF, F)]`

  As you can see, the right-most value can be a "good" pivot.

  After the first iteration, `D` is already in its right place
- 2nd. iteration:

  `[[QuickSort(A,A), B, QuickSort(C,C)], D, [QuickSort(E,E), F, QuickSort(G,G)]]`
- Result:

  `[A, B, C, D, E, F, G]`

Punch line: Even if you take the right-most entry of the array, there may be cases where that entry is a "good" pivot value.

The *real* worst case would be applying quick sort on an already sorted array. But the same rules apply. Try to apply the above process to something like this: `QuickSort(ABCDEFG, G)`

Comment: So in the case of QuickSort(ABCDEFG, G) would the contents of the array never actually change position? Would it then become QuickSort(ABCDEF,F),G, then QuickSort(ABCDE,E),F,G and so on?

Comment: @Jackson Exactly... It's easy to see why that's the *real **worst** case*, don't you think? ;-)

Comment: Yep! It has to break down the array for each element, as well as make n-1 comparisons. Thanks!!

Comment: @Jackson Quicksort has an average performance of *`O(n * log(n) )`* and a worst performance of *`O(n²)`*. [See here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort)